# Find unique rows in a boolean matrix (help resolve garbage output from std::string)

Tags: c++, matrix, stl

I'm trying to find duplicate rows in a matrix by storing each row as a string in a hashmap, against a count.  All the strings with counts <=1 are my unique rows.

The output of the program looks complete garbage.  Instead of rows, this is the output I'm getting :

```
110101101010100
110101101110110
```

Please let me know what could be the mistake ?

Input Matrix :

```
int matrix[M][N] =
        {{0, 1, 0, 0, 1},
        {1, 0, 1, 1, 0},
        {0, 1, 0, 0, 1},
        {1, 0, 1, 0, 0}};
```

Code :

```
void printUniqRows(int mat[M][N])
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    std::map<std::string, int> rowMap;
    for (i=0;i<M;i++)
    {
        std::stringstream *s1 = new std::stringstream();
        std::string *inp = new std::string();
        for (j=0;j<N;j++)
        {
            *s1 << mat[i][j];
            *inp+= s1->str();
        }
        rowMap[*inp]++;
        delete s1;
        delete inp;
    }
    std::cout<<"Unique rows in the matrix are ....\n";
    for (std::map<std::string, int>::iterator it = rowMap.begin();it!=rowMap.end();++it)
    {
        if (it->second <=1)
        {
            std::cout<<it->first.c_str()<<"\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `std::stringstream *s1 = new std::stringstream();` What? Why not `std::stringstream s1;` Don't make things harder for yourself.

Comment: you've used new/delete . why? You should google RAII and avoid unnecessary new/delete. Maybe you are a c# programmer?

Comment: Tried that at first, but looking at the output i suspected it could be happening due to appending extra chars to stringstream, hence i implemented new & delete to clear the buffer everytime.  The output is the same irrespective of new/delete or static initialization !

Answer (score 1):

remove the `inp` variable everywhere, except for thr last instance and replace

```
rowMap[*inp]++;
```

with

```
rowMap[s1->str()];
```

Your bug is that you need to move this line

```
 *inp+= s1->str();
```

outside the inner loop.

Comment: Wow ! That really solved the issue.  But, could you elaborate more on why this fix ? What was wrong with using std::string inp ?

Comment: The problem is that you were appending `s1` to the string `inp`. But `s1` gets appended itself with the `<<` operator. So you were doubly appending. The whole point of the `<<` operator on a `stringstream` is to append several items.